# C Programming Help with Int2String method

Tags: c, string, integer

I am having trouble with my Int2String method.  I am new to C so I am not sure if this would be the correct way to go about it.  I'm receiving a few error messages:

error: conflicting types for 'int2String'
warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast

Here is my method:

```
char int2String(int num, char intStr[10]) {
char itoa(num, intStr[10]);
return itoa;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: why don't you use itoa directly or create an alias using typedef ?

Comment: how do I accept sorry I'm new....nvm got it

Comment: no problem, everyone was new once. Next to each answer (on a question you ask) there is a check mark. If you click it, it will turn green indicating that this is the answer you have accepted. That is: this is the answer that you think best addresses what you asked. Also, the arrows above and below all questions and answers are for voting whether you think these are good or bad questions/answers. This is also the primary way that reputation is earned. About 1/2 way down this page [ http://stackoverflow.com/faq ] explains more.

Comment: Hi, my question is: what are you *trying* to do? Are you trying to make an integer value (say, 42) "printable" on a screen? Or do you want to "translate" an integer value into something like "fourty-two"? Perhaps there's a simpler method and you're just making your life so much complicated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code

```
char itoa(num, intStr[10]);
return itoa;
```

tells the compiler that you *declare* a function called `itoa` with specific signature, then you want to *return (a pointer to) this function*. Since you declared the return type as `char`, the compiler doesn't like this.

It should rather look something like

```
char int2String(int num, char intStr[10]) {
  char ch = itoa(num, intStr);
  return ch;
}
```

i.e. *call* the function [`itoa`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) with given parameters, store its return value in a local variable of type `char`, then return it. (The local variable could be inlined to simplify the code.)

Now this still does not make the compiler happy, since `itoa`, although not part of the standard, is by convention declared to return `char*`, and to take 3 parameters, not 2. (Unless you use a nonstandard definition if `itoa`, that is.)

With the "standard" `itoa` version, this modification should work (in theory at least - I have not tested it :-)

```
char* int2String(int num, char intStr[10]) {
  return itoa(num, intStr, 10);
}
```

Comment: The return type of `itoa` is `char*` not `char`.

Comment: @Nikolai, I have dealt with that in the meantime :-)

Comment: I'm still receiving the same error with the compiler. Unable to resolve identifier.

Comment: This may be due to the absence of itoa in your compiler. Simply use snprintf and go standard.

Comment: @Jogan, have you #included the header file which declares `itoa` in your specific C environment?

Comment: I included the stdlib.h which declares the itoa function.

Comment: itoa is not C89/C99. Therefore your example is not strict ANSI C.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from being curious as to why you are wrapping a non-standard function like this, there a couple things wrong with your function.

1. Your `int2String` function should return a `char *` instead of `char`.  As you have it you are saying "`int2String` returns a character" which I presume is not what you want.  In C strings are represented as an array of characters so you should be returning an array which is a pointer to the type of element stored in the array (in this case pointer to `char`).
2. Although technically valid, the `intStr` parameter is written in a rather bizarre manner.  The reason this works is because the `char intStr[10]` notation is equivalent to `char *intStr`, which is what it really should be.
3. First of all the `itoa` function is non-standard function, so it is very much implementation dependent.  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itoa) the declaration for `itoa` is `void itoa(int input, char *buffer, int radix)`.  That being said you need to allocate a buffer and fill it using `itoa`.  I'll leave this as a little exercise :)
4. Finally, your return statement is what is causing the error.  Since `itoa` is a function what you have written says "return the function `itoa`".  This means you are trying to return a function (which can be represented as a pointer) where the compiler is expecting a `char`.

I would highly recommend you check out [The C Book](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/), it provides a great introduction to the language and goes to great lengths to clarify what pointers are and how they are used.  Another couple resources worth checking out are:

- [C Programming](http://www2.its.strath.ac.uk/courses/c/)
- [The GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/index.html#Top)

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning char* rather than char.